# vsftpd: 550 Failed to change directory

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I'm using ubuntu 12.04. and `ftp` service I've installed `vsftpd` and it's working fine. But may I'm facing some user complexity.

My system directory like:

```
-/
--/home
----/rony
--/vol
```

When I list directories through `ftp`, it's going to `/rony` first. But when I `cd /vol` or `cd ..`, it's showing `550 Failed to change directory` error.

Answer (score 1):

As http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes states,

> 550   Requested action not taken. File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

You either don't have file system permissions to access these directories or the server is set up such that it treats `/home` as the file system root.

You could of course have googled a bit and found something like http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/550-failed-to-change-directory-835003/